# Filling hole after removing medicine cabinet

Tags: bathroom, hole

I have a mirror that is larger than the hole left from removing a medicine cabinet in our bathroom, and I plan to mount it so it covers the hole entirely. I don't want to just leave the empty hole there, though.

I'd prefer not to seal up the hole with drywall as I believe at some point we may put another medicine cabinet in that room. I would like to put some insulation in there and I need something to hold that insulation in place.

Any recommendations? Would some sort of plastic be OK to cover the hole and hold in the insulation?

Comment: Is this an exterior wall?

Comment: Yes, this is exterior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plastic stapled to the face of the wall will work as you noted. Also any thin veneer such as a door skin so it overlaps the opening will prove to be a bit more rigid if that matters and is easily cut with a utility knife.

if you can't hit he studs the door skin should still remain in place with only some small box head-type nails.

Comment: I think the residential building codes used in most jurisdictions require covering insulation with drywall, plaster or wood products of specified fire-resistance specifications.